# Recurrent file system corruption

Tags: boot, hard-drive, filesystem

I was running Ubuntu version 16 with three drives: the system drive was a magnetic internal hard drive, there was a solid-state internal drive and an external, USB-connected magnetic drive.

About a week ago, the file systems on all three drives got corrupted. I never found the cause. I reformatted the drives and installed Ubuntu 20.04 and reconstructed the contents of the file system on the system drive. When I rebooted today, it sent into grub. Using ls to examine the drives, there was no ext4 file system. I can only conclude that the file systems were again corrupted.

So my question is, is there any remaining possibility that the cause could be in software or is it necessarily the drives or a controller?

The second question, which might be out of scope for this forum, would be how to test the hardware.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 (a *yy* or *year* only release) is a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (a *yy.mm* or *year.month* release).  Ubuntu has two different products which are differentiated using the *year* or *year.month* name.  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 16?  as there is no Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Use the drive's inbuilt SMART to test your drive health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) but note even good hardware will perform badly when RAM is faulty (so test RAM), or PSU is faulty (check PSU), and I'd also do a *cap-scan* or quick visual check of the motherboard etc. looking for swollen capacitors or other signs of failure....

Comment: The RAM has been tested.

Comment: I ran the SMART test and no errors were reported. Booting to a live USB stick shows the drives looking normal, but it still boots into the grub prompt. The grub directory is there, as is grub.cfg.

Comment: I predominately use standard releases, not specialist *snap* only releases (that are *year* only in format like Ubuntu Core 16), and have no experience in switching a *snap* only system (16) to a standard system (20.04) though doubt there is difference that would impact your issue. I'd likely check your *file-system-table* to ensure UUIDs match the real drives; details in the grub.cfg match your system etc.

Comment: I know how to find the UUIDs in fstab, but I don't know how to determine if they point to the correct drives.. I tried to use "ls -l" in the grub command prompt, but I get "invalid file name -l"

Comment: I tried to use "ls -l" in the grub command prompt, but I get "invalid file name -l" The UUID for root in grub.cfg matches the UUID in for root in fstab, but I didn't see the UUID for the EFI partition in grub.cfg, so I did was not able to compare it to the one in fstab.

Comment: `sudo blkid` will list block device IDs.  Grub rescue is a very limited program given it can only be 512 bytes total in size; using *live* media to explore makes more sense to me.

Comment: OK I used live media and verify that every reference to UUID in grub.cfg matches my system drive. The UUID for efi in fstab does not appear in grub.cfg. Should it? Incidentally it boots into the grub command line, not the grub rescue

Comment: I see that one of the lines in fstab refers to a UUID that doesn't show up when I give the command "ls -o /dev/disk/by-uuid." From my limited knowledge, that seems like a problem

Comment: So I edited fstab and put in the UUID of the EFI partition that is identified by gparted, but it still boots into grub

Comment: I have been looking at grub.cfg on my system drive. There is also a much shorter grub.cfg in my EFI partition. It has a UUID that doesn't seem to correspond to any device on the machine

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding grub.cfg did not help and trying to fix the UUID for my EFI partition also did not work. However, the fix [here](https://www.tecmint.com/rescue-repair-and-reinstall-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu/), which rebuilds more of the boot information or the boot partition, resulted in a successful repair.